# i want to get the name of the checkboxes clicked and store the names of these checkboxes in a database(sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-listview

i want to create a custom list view in which it should contain  checkboxes.Onclicking the checkboxes i want to get the name of the checkboxes clicked and store the names of these checkboxes in a database(sqlite).Can anyone help be to jump this riddle???

Comment: Do you have any code? Best place to start is http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custome ListAdapter something like [this](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview).. but one single change is you need to tag the converTview with the CheckBox using `setTag()`.. and in ListView's click listener just say `view.getTag()` which will give you checkBox..then say `checkBox.getText()`